# React-add-msal getAccessToken unable to load from cache

Tags: reactjs, msal.js

I'm trying to use react-aad-msal. Everything works well (I can fetch my token from Azure) until I try to get it from the cache. 
When I use the getAccessToken() method the page reloads again and again. It seems msal is unable to load the token from the cache. I tried the these solutions ([Application does not fetch access token from cache using MSAL (react-aad-msal)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59789433/application-does-not-fetch-access-token-from-cache-using-msal-react-aad-msal)) but it didn't work.
Do you have any idea ?

Here my config:

```
import jwt from 'jwt-decode'
import { MsalAuthProvider, LoginType } from 'react-aad-msal';

// Msal Configurations
const config: any = {
  auth: {
    authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>',
    clientId: '<frontEndClientID>',
    redirectUri: 'http://localhost:3000/signin-oidc'
  },
  cache: {
    cacheLocation: "localStorage",
    storeAuthStateInCookie: false
  }
};

// Authentication Parameters
const authenticationParameters = {
  scopes: [
    "https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read",
    "api://<backEndAPIClientID>/Room.ReadWrite"
  ]
}

// Options
const options = {
  loginType: LoginType.Redirect,
  tokenRefreshUri: window.location.origin + '/auth.html'
}

export const authProvider = new MsalAuthProvider(config, authenticationParameters, options)

export const authenticateRequest = async (headers: any) => {
  // Get the authentication token 
  const token = await authProvider.getAccessToken();
  console.log(jwt(token.accessToken));
  return {
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      authorization: token.accessToken ? `Bearer ${token.accessToken}` : "",
    }
  } 
};
```

And here my request:

```
export async function getAllRooms(options: object) {
    let queryOptions = "?";
    Object.entries(options).forEach(
    ([key, value]) => {
    queryOptions = queryOptions.concat(key).concat("=").concat(value).concat("&");
        } 
    );
    return axios.get(endpoint + queryOptions, await authenticateRequest({}))
    .then(response => {
        ...
    })
    .catch(err => {
        throw err
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've finally managed to make it work. In my authProvider.getAccessToken() I was requesting for 2 scopes from 2 different APIs and it seems that AzureAD doesn't like that. I have removed one and voila.

I'm still wondering why though. Maybe a misconfiguration somewhere in Azure.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-spa-acquire-token?tabs=react

```
const onRequest = async (config: AxiosRequestConfig): Promise<AxiosRequestConfig> => {
    var accessToken: any;
    //acquireTokenSilent first checks the cache in browser storage to see if a valid token exists and returns it. 
    //When no valid token is in the cache, it attempts to use its refresh token to get the token.
    await authProvider.acquireTokenSilent(authenticationParametersGraph)
        .then(accessTokenResponse => {
            // Acquire token silent success
            accessToken = accessTokenResponse.idToken.rawIdToken;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            //Acquire token silent failure
            if (error instanceof InteractionRequiredAuthError)
               accessToken = authProvider.acquireTokenRedirect(authenticationParametersGraph)
            console.log("token error", error);
        });
    config.headers!["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${accessToken}`;
    config.headers!["Accept"] = 'application/json';
    config.withCredentials = true;
    return config;
}
```